# Array is null in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this array:

```
productCarts: ProductModel[] = [];
```

And when I call this method in ngInit  I have error `Cannot read property 'length' of null`:

```
addProductFromLocalStorage() {

            if (this.productCarts.length == 0) {
                this.productCarts  = this.fromLocalStorage;  
            } 
    }
```

Solution:
My local storage return the null value and I hade exception.

Comment: It seems like `this.fromLocalStorage` is `null`

Comment: you may be assigning null to productsCarts somewhere.

Comment: give a bit more context. most likely you loose the this context when calling addProductFromLocalStorage().

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
addProductFromLocalStorage() {

            if (!this.productCarts || this.productCarts.length === 0) {
                this.productCarts  = this.fromLocalStorage;  
            } 
    }
```

`!this.productCarts`  this will check null and undefined value

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try using,

```
addProductFromLocalStorage() {

        if (this.productCarts === undefined || this.productCarts.length == 0) {
            this.productCarts  = this.fromLocalStorage;  
        } 
}
```

The is error `Cannot read property 'length' of null` is  encountered as `this.productCarts` has not been defined yet.
You can also use the second approach as declare `productCarts:ProductModel[]` in the global execution context and in ngInit method mention `this.productCarts = []`. Using this approach would also help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue with the latest Typescript 3.7 feature called optional chaining:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#optional-chaining

Comment: I hade a problem because my local storage returns the null.